# Why does this code return a long number at the end? (c++)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int funky(int stuff)
{
    int number;
    number = 10;
    cout << "Please enter a number \n";
    cin >> number;
    stuff = number + 777;
    cout << "The result is " << stuff << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    
    funky(num1);
    funky(num2);
    
    cout << num1 << "  and  " << num2;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to learn to use functions in C++, but i cannot figure out why this code returns a very long negative number at the end . can someone tell me why num2 returns a very long number? it doesnt make sense to me at all

Comment: You aren't catching the return as well. Make it void or something.

Comment: When facing the situation *"i cannot figure out why [X]"*, it is sometimes useful to step back and ask if [X] is in fact true. Because figuring out why [X] is true is very, very difficult when [X] is false. ;)

Comment: Let's face it, it's called undefined behavior.

Comment: Turn on your compiler's warnings.  It should have been able to tell you where some of your problems are in your code.

Comment: @cigien Sorry, you're right. Parameters can legally be used in assignments function locally. Won't have no effect to the passed variables though, and such these stay uninitialized, and everything after the function calls done with them is UB.

Comment: @arundeepchohan There's generally no problem with unused return values. Maybe you confuse this with missing ones from inside a function that defines a return type.

Comment: Well for ints there are no problems for discarding unused return values but in this case, there was no reason of having a return value at all.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, your intention was to assign `stuff` inside the function and use as `num1` and `num2` in `main()`. To do it, you need to change your parameter type from `int` to `int&`, i.e. pass by reference. Your function declaration should be `int funky(int& stuff)`.

The way you defined the function, variables `num1` and `num2`remain uninitialized, that's why `cout << num1 << "  and  " << num2;` is printing garbage.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that are wrong with your code . For one, you do not need a *value-returning function*. You could instead use `void`.

You also are getting [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) by not *initializing* your variables `int num1` and `int num2`.

Now, an alternative to your problem would be using `void`. (If you only need two numbers.) Other than that I suggest using @Eugene's answer.

Replace:

`int funky(int stuff)` to `void funky(int stuff)`.

For Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void funky()
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;

    cout << "Please enter a number \n";
    cin >> num1;
    int Res1 = num1 + 777;
    cout << "The result is " << Res1 << endl;


    cout << "Please enter one more number \n";
    cin >> num2;
    int Res2 = num2 + 777;

    cout << "The result is " << Res2 << endl;


    cout << num1 << " and " << num2;
    
    
}

int main()
{

    funky();

    return 0;
}
```